# Sponsorship of drupalcon

Tags: discussion

Listening to the SE podcast it was mentioned that SE would potentially sponsor conferences to help promote SE sites.

Would it be a great help to raise awareness of this site if they were to sponsor DrupalCon London?

I think there are still [some sponsorship slots](http://london2011.drupal.org/sponsor-now) left.

Comment: It would be great if it could happen.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that the podcast was not talking of sponsoring a person who would talk in a conference? As far as I remember, that is what has been already done for other SE sites, or has been proposed for other sites. See [Are there any English language conferences to which SE could sponsor a member?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/747/are-there-any-english-language-conferences-to-which-se-could-sponsor-a-member)

Comment: I could have miss understood. Drupal Cons are free to speakers (if your proposal gets accepted). So I'm not sure how that would work in this case?

Comment: Drupalcos are free, but you still have to reach the place where the Drupalcon is kept. If sponsorship is all about money, that could be a way to sponsorship a person.

Comment: Very true, We may be too late for DC London in that case, but perhaps for the next US one there could be a contest or something on DA to win a sponsorship. Although I quite like the sound of the Stack Exchange party.