# Promotion at Drupalcon Denver

Tags: discussion

Hopefully, I'll be able to attend [Drupalcon Denver](http://denver2012.drupal.org/) (march 2012). **How can I / other attendees help promote this site?** Or, on the other hand, is promotion necessary?

There is a similar question and an answer here: [How do we promote Drupal Answers?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-promote-drupal-answers/15#15)

And a sponsorship question here about London: [Sponsorship of drupalcon](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/sponsorship-of-drupalcon)

Unfortunately, not much activity or feedback occurred in those posts, so I'm hoping to get some discussion here in preparation for the next con 6 months from now.

Just a few ideas to get discussion rolling:

- [Sponsor the conference](http://denver2012.drupal.org/sponsors) (or perhaps let a member "win" a ticket?)
- Create small ads (e.g. stickers, buttons, etc) for distribution

Answer (score 3):

Sure -- see

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/

For a fairly complete list of ways we can support you in this.